# Additional Textboxes are appear in csv file exporting from SSRS report

Tags: excel, csv, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

While exporting the ssrs reports to csv files it contains some additional columns like ‘textbox15’, textbox8’ etc which contains the data also. It is appear in XML also. In excel we are getting the correct data. It does not appear in excel. Getting the correct data in excel sheet. I could not find any textboxes with these names in report designer. How can I find out these hidden textboxes?

The report in csv,xml,excel is given below

[image]

Comment: These cells may not show up in the report designer, but they are in the XML code behind (right click RDL, view code). Backup your work before making any changes to the XML code. Excel and PDF are smart enough not to display those cells. I would check a few things: Do you have nested text boxes? Or do you have 'parent' rectangles with text boxes inside? You don't see them in the Properties drop down?

Answer (score 3):

It can be very tedious, but you can use the DataElement properties to control what/how particular parts of your report show up on data-only export types (CSV, XML).  In Visual Studio, these are under the "Data Only" section of the properties pane.

"DataElementOutput" will control whether or not a particular item will show up in a data export - "NoOutput" will prevent it from being included, while "Output", and usually "Auto" will include the data.

The other properties (DataElementName, DataElementStyle) will provide finer control over XML formatting, and DataElementName can also be used to specify column headers for CSV exports.

Answer (score 0):

In the SSRS report Design select the column header for "projectcode" . in the textbox properties for the "Projectcode"[Click on the column header so that it will select the textbox for the header and show the properties] Select the dataelementoutput from "Auto" to "No Output". Make sure you change the property of the the dataelementoutput to "No Output" only for the header not for the entire column.